# My genetic algorithm won't converge/reaches local minima

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm

I've been struggling with this little project for a while and I'd really appreciate your help.

I'm trying to build a genetic algorithm for drawing pictures using transparent shapes (triangles), something like this: https://chriscummins.cc/s/genetics/, but I've tried a lot of different hyperparameters and different techniques and I can't really get any convergence like the website above does. Sometimes it'll run for a long time and it'll still get stuck in stuff like the image below, which seems like it's converged to something, since there are not many different individuals, but it's not quite there!

[image: Last generation's best individual]

The algorithm works basically likes this:

- Every individual in the population is a Painting on a empty/black canvas of a fixed number of triangles.
- Fitness of an individual is calculated by doing a pixel-wise Mean Absolute Error between an individual's painting and the target image.
- I use tournament selection to select which individuals can be chosen to breed to produce the next generation's individuals.
- Crossover between two paintings is basically randomly selecting half of each parent's genes, which is their triangles.
- The mutation consists of basically applying some change to the vertices' coordinates of each triangle in the painting.
- I apply mutations to the children generation.
- The best of each generation always automatically advances to the next generation. (Elitism)

I'll attach code below, hope it's understandable, tried to document it to make it easier for people to help me out.

Here is my **Triangle (Gene)** class:

```py
class Triangle:

    def __init__(self, image):
        '''
        Parameters
        ------------

        image: PIL.Image
            Image where the triangle will be drawn.

            This must be passed in order for the random triangle's vertices
            to have correct coordinates.
        '''
        self.max_width, self.max_height = image.size
        self.vertices = self.random_polygon()

        # RGBA
        self.color = Triangle.random_color()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Vertices: {[(round(x, 2), round(y, 2)) for (x, y) in self.vertices]} | Color: {self.color}'

    def draw(self, draw_object, fill=True) -> None:
        '''
        Method to draw the polygon using a Pillow ImageDraw.Draw object

        Parameters
        ------------

        draw_object: ImageDraw.Draw
            Object to draw the image

        fill: bool
            Whether to fill the polygon or just outline it.

        '''

        if fill:
            draw_object.polygon(self.vertices, fill=self.color)
        else:
            draw_object.polygon(self.vertices, outline=self.color)

    def noise(self, ratio):
        '''Generate noise into this object'''

        def vertex_noise(vertex):
            x, y = vertex
            x = random.uniform(max(0.0, x - ratio * x), min(self.max_width, x + ratio * x))
            y = random.uniform(max(0.0, y - ratio * y), min(self.max_height, y + ratio * y))
            return (x, y)

        for i in range(3):
            self.vertices[i] = vertex_noise(self.vertices[i])

        return self

    def random_polygon(self) -> list:
        '''Generate a random triangle in the form [(x, y), (x, y), (x, y)]'''

        def random_vertex() -> tuple:
            x = random.uniform(0.0, self.max_width)
            y = random.uniform(0.0, self.max_height)
            return (x, y)

        return [random_vertex() for _ in range(3)]

    @classmethod
    def random_color(cls) -> tuple:
        '''Generate a random RGBA color tuple'''
        def _random(lower, upper):
            return random.randint(lower, upper)

        return (_random(0, 255), _random(0, 255), _random(0, 255), _random(85, 255))

    @classmethod
    def collection(cls, size, image) -> list:
        '''
        Generate collection of triangles

        Parameters
        ------------

        size: int
            Number of triangles to generate

        image: PIL.Image
            Image to use for the Triangle constructor.
            See help(Triangle) for more info.

        Return
        --------

        collection: list
            Collection of polygons.

        '''
        return [cls(image) for _ in range(size)]
```

And here's the **Painting (Individual)** class:

```py
class Painting:
    def __init__(self, num_objects, img):
        '''
        Parameters
        ------------

        num_objects: int
            Number of triangles in each painting (this is the DNA size).

        img: PIL.Image
            Target image that we're trying to approximate

        '''
        self.polygons = Triangle.collection(num_objects, img)
        self.target = img
        self.fitness = float('inf')

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.fitness < other.fitness

    def __del__(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'canvas'):
            self.canvas.close() 

    def fit(self):
        '''Fits individual's painted canvas against target image'''
        self.paint()
        self.fitness = self._error(self.canvas, self.target)   
        return self

    @classmethod
    def crossover(cls, indA, indB, ratio):
        '''
        Reproduces two painting objects and generates a painting child
        by randomly choosing genes from each parent in some given proportion.

        Parameters
        ------------

        indA: Painting

        indB: Painting

        ratio: float
            Proportion of genes to be taken from the father object.

        Return
        ---------

        child: Painting
        '''
        if len(indA.polygons) != len(indB.polygons):
            raise ValueError('Parents\' number of polygons don\'t match.')

        if indA.target != indB.target:
            raise ValueError('Parents\' target images don\'t match.')

        num_objects = len(indA.polygons)
        target = indA.target
        child = cls(num_objects, target)

        indA_ratio = int(ratio * num_objects)

        # Crossover Parents' triangles
        child.polygons = deepcopy(random.sample(indA.polygons, k=indA_ratio))
        child.polygons.extend(deepcopy(random.sample(indB.polygons, k=num_objects-indA_ratio)))

        return child

    @classmethod
    def random_population(cls, size, num_objs, img):
        '''Generates a random population of paintings'''
        return [cls(num_objs, img) for _ in range(size)]

    def mutate(self, mutation_chance, mutation_ratio):
        '''
        Applies noise to the painting objects' genes, which is basically a "mutation"

        Parameters
        ------------

        mutation_chance: float
            chance that each gene will be mutated

        mutation_ratio: float
            intensity of the mutation that will be caused in case it happens.

            The noise caused is just a small change in the polygons' vertices coordinates.

            See help(Painting.noise()) for more info.
        '''
        num_objs = len(self.polygons)

        rng = random.uniform(0.0, 1.0)

        if mutation_chance < rng:
            return self

        for i in range(num_objs):
            rng = random.uniform(0.0, 1.0)

            if mutation_chance < rng:
                continue

            self.polygons[i].noise(mutation_ratio)

        return self

    def paint(self):
        '''Paints genoma into an empty canvas.'''
        if hasattr(self, 'canvas'):
            self.canvas.close()

        # Create white canvas
        self.canvas = Image.new(mode='RGB', size=self.target.size)
        draw_obj = ImageDraw.Draw(self.canvas, mode='RGBA')

        for poly in self.polygons:
            poly.draw(draw_obj)

    @staticmethod
    def _error(canvas, target):
        '''Mean Squared Error between PIL Images'''
        r_canvas, g_canvas, b_canvas = canvas.split()
        r_target, g_target, b_target = target.split()

        def mse(a, b):
            return np.square(np.subtract(a, b)).mean()

        return (mse(r_canvas, r_target) + mse(g_canvas, g_target) + mse(b_canvas, b_target)) / 3.0
```

At last, this is the general flow of the algorithm itself:

```py
def k_way_tournament_selection(population, number_of_winners, K=3):
    selected = []
    while len(selected) < number_of_winners:
        fighters = random.sample(population, k=min(number_of_winners-len(selected), K))

        selected.append(min(fighters))

    return selected

EPOCHS = 200
POP_SIZE = 100
DNA_SIZE = 100
MUTATION_CHANCE = 0.01
MUTATION_RATIO = 0.2
SELECTION_RATIO = 0.3

pop = Painting.random_population(POP_SIZE, DNA_SIZE, lisa)
initial = time()
generation_best = []

for ep in range(EPOCHS):
    pop = [p.fit() for p in pop]
    pop = sorted(pop)

    # Save Best
    best = pop[0]
    generation_best.append(deepcopy(best.canvas))
    pop = pop[1:]


    # Tournament selection
    selected = []
    selected = k_way_tournament_selection(pop, int(len(pop) * SELECTION_RATIO))
    selected.append(best)

    # Reproduce
    children = []
    while len(children) < POP_SIZE:
        indA = random.choice(selected)
        indB = random.choice(selected)

        cross = Painting.crossover(indA, indB, 0.5)
        children.append(cross)

    # Mutate
    children = [child.mutate(MUTATION_CHANCE, MUTATION_RATIO) for child in children]
    children.append(best)

    pop = deepcopy(children)

    del children
    del selected
    gc.collect()

    t = time()
    print(f'EPOCH: {ep} | SIZE: {len(pop)} | ELAPSED: {round(t - initial, 2)}s | BEST: {best.fitness}')
```

Comment: If you view the source for that (pretty cool) web page there is a link to a git hub repository which has the source code. Perhaps you could look at that and see what it is doing that your code isn't.

Comment: @JohnColeman Yes, I'm trying to take a deep look into it, though I'm not very good at JS. The general idea is very similar, so my fear is that there's some logical Python error that I'm not seeing, since I'm biased. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: The _error function used to determine fitness isn't what I expected. I'm not suggesting it's wrong but I had assumed it would be euclidean distance

Comment: I think your mutate function is wrong. It seems like the way it's written it's making it really hard to inject randomness. You have the initial mutation_chance check but then it checks again for each object. If your chance of mutation is say 40% the chance of each object mutating is only 16%.

Comment: You could also consider changing how the crossover selection works. It's fixed at 50/50 objects from A and B (based on current parameters). Instead you could put all the objects into an array and randomly select from the array until you have enough. Forcing a fixed selection from A and B eliminates many possible solutions.

Comment: Hi @gph, thanks a lot for the comments. I'm gonna try using euclidean distance. I do have a feeling there's something with the _error function, because I actually let the algorithm run for like an hour and it reached something pretty weird: [weird_best](https://i.imgur.com/gzGY4Jd.jpg) . The target image is this monalisa picture: [monalisa](https://i.imgur.com/tLqi21G.jpg) I feel like the triangle placement seems correct but the colors got messed up?

Comment: I understand what you're saying about the mutation, I think at first this if statement was from a previous version and I kept it by mistake, I think it was only supposed to calculate the mutation chance for each polygon, which makes more sense.

Comment: I'll try the random crossover too. Thanks a lot for all of your suggestions, super helpful!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215444/discussion-between-thiago-preischadt-and-gph).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I found the major bug!

The problem is in the _error function. Whenever PIL images get converted to numpy arrays (when calling `np.subtract()` between two 2D numpy arrays, which are the image channels), it gets converted to  a numpy array of type `np.uint8` (unsigned int 8 bytes), because images are in the range [0-255], which makes sense. But when using `np.subtract`, if you get a negative value, then it will underflow, and your fitness function will be messed up.

In order to fix that, just cast the image channel with `np.array(channel, np.int32)` before doing `np.subtract()`